# Is the boundary Dehn twist central in the mapping class group of surface or not? [resolved]

Tags: mapping-class-group

Please help me find a mistake and resolve a paradox:

Let $S$ be an orientable surface of genus $g\ge 2$ with $n\ge 1$ boundary components. Consider $T_\partial$, the Dehn twist about a curve parallel to some boundary component $\partial$. There are two facts:

1) The mapping class group of $S$ is generated by the Dehn twists about nonseparating simple closed curves. (See Corollary 4.16 in Farb & Margalit's book: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/farbmarg.pdf )

2) A mapping class $f$ commutes with the Dehn twist $T_c$ about a curve $c$ if and only if $f(c)$ is isotopic to $c$ or $\bar c$. (See Fact 3.8 in  http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/farbmarg.pdf )

An immediate corollary:

**$T_\partial$ is central in the mapping class group of $S$.**

Indeed, for any nonseparating simple closed curve $c$, $c$ and $\partial$ are disjoint, hence $T_c(\partial)\simeq\partial$, and so $T_\partial$ commutes with all generators of the mapping class group.

However, this corollary is in contradiction with the following facts:

3) The center of the mapping class group of $S$ is trivial ( p. 77 in http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/farbmarg.pdf ) [**UPDATE: This is true for surfaces with punctures, but not with boundary components!**]

4) $T_\partial$ is a nontrivial mapping class (Proposition 3.1 in http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/farbmarg.pdf).

I am very confused now.

Comment: Perhaps this question is better asked on math overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I found where I was confusing myself. The fact 3), as cited from Farb and Margalit's book, deals with *surfaces with punctures*, but not with *surfaces with boundary components*. For the latter, it is indeed true that boundary twists are central, and hence the center is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^n$, if $n$ is the number of boundary components. Let me quote the sentence on p. 77 of Farb and Margalit's book:

"By the same argument, for a surface with boundary, **the Dehn twist about any boundary component is central**."